# How do I create a list with the number I want in a loop?

Tags: python, list

Say I want to create a new list every (in a loop) time the variable i (an integer) changes, eg:

```
game_1 = []

game_2 = []

game_3 = []

...

game_i = []
```

How would I do this?

I've tried putting `game_i`, which obviously doesn't work; neither does `game[i]`,

Comment: Your variables should be a list: `games = [[], [], [],...]`

Comment: So you're saying put game_1, game_2 inside games?

Comment: You put what should have been the values of your variables into the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gb = globals()
for i in range(10):
    gb['game_{0}'.format(i)] = []
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are trying to dynamically name variables. This issue has been discussed before, check [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) for details of alternatives.

Edit:  second link you should consider [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Comment: Yes, dynamically sounds right. I didn't know the terminology

Comment: Thank you. These links seem better than my list approach